# Select top record from group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to from this table

```
Name  Code
ABC     Code1
DEF     Code1
GHI     Code2
JKL     Code2
OMN     Code3
```

get this result:

```
Name  Code
ABC   Code1
GHI   Code2
OMN   Code3
```

Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I considered that you want your results to be alphabetical.

```
SELECT
         MIN(Name), Code
FROM 
         MyTable 
GROUP BY 
         Code
```

Comment: sorry, I change Code to Name.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MIN(Name),Code
FROM Table
GROUP BY Code
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT MIN(c1), c2 FROM table GROUP BY c2 ORDER BY c2 ASC;

Answer (score 1):

if your "TOP" is defined by "first in alphabtetical order", you could simply use a simple group by clause with the MIN aggregation.

```
SELECT MIN(Col1), Col2 FROM table GROUP BY Col2
```

otherwise, you will need another column, such as an incrementing uniqueid or a creation date.